# Области видимости в Питоне

Tags: python

мне нужна переменная, которую я смогу использовать в нескольких функциях. Как ее определить?

```
listofimagesinfolder = []
def readrasterfolder():
    #КУСОК КОДА ВЫКИНУТ
        listofimagesinfolder.append(filename)
print listofimagesinfolder # получается, что тут listofimagesinfolder будет пустым, так?
```

Как мне сделать его видимым глобально?

Вот большой кусок кода:

```
#Читаем растры которые есть в каталоге
listofimagesinfolder = []
def readrasterfolder():
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(gvar.rasterfolder):
        # На каждой итерации получаем список элементов одного из каталогов и дсоставляем общий список
        # И фильтруем по расширению
        for filename in files:
            if filename.endswith('.img'):
                #print filename
                listofimagesinfolder.append(filename)
print "Dir have next images:"
print "================================START IMAGES LIST==============================="
for image in listofimagesinfolder:
    print image
print "=================================END IMAGES LIST================================"
print gvar.dbhost
print ('LIST OF IMAGES: {0}').format(listofimagesinfolder) # ВОТ ТУТ ПРОБЛЕМА
################TEMP######################################
# Получаем данные из столбцов ГДБ и сравниваем их с растрами в каталоге
fields = ["Name", "OBJECTID"]
arrayofimagesingdb = []
c = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mdname, fields[1])
for row in c:
    #print (('{0}, {1}').format(row[1],row[0]))
    arrayofimagesingdb.extend(row)
print "============"
print ("IN DB: ", arrayofimagesingdb)
print ("IN FOLDER: ", listofimagesinfolder)
print "============"

a = list(set(listofimagesinfolder)&set(arrayofimagesingdb))
################TEMP########################################
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По умолчанию, все переменные внутри функции - локальные. И их изменение не влияет на внешние переменные. В Вашем случае `listofimagesinfolder` - две разные переменные. Поэтому и получаете подобное поведение. Исправляется несколькими способами.

способ первый, дедовский - добавить global

```
listofimagesinfolder = []
def readrasterfolder():
    global listofimagesinfolder
    #КУСОК КОДА ВЫКИНУТ
        listofimagesinfolder.append(filename)
print listofimagesinfolder
```

способ два - процедурный - передать как параметр

```
listofimagesinfolder = []
def readrasterfolder(listofimagesinfolder):
    #КУСОК КОДА ВЫКИНУТ
        listofimagesinfolder.append(filename)
print listofimagesinfolder
```

способ третий, хитрый - использовать nonlocal, но я так глубоко не знаю питон. Это похоже на обычный global.

Способ четыре, ООПшный - если есть потребность в одной переменной, доступной для нескольких процедур, значит нужно все это завернуть в один класс.

```
class ImagesList:
    def __init__(self): # это типа конструктор
        self.imagelist = []

    def readFromFolder(self, forlder):
        for i in list_of_files:
            self.imagelist.append(i)

    def print(self):
        for i in self.imagelist:
            print (i)

# использование

l = ImagesList()
l.readFromFolder('~/Images')
l.print()
```

Comment: Вот! Ваш ответ многое проясняет! Не могли бы пример показать того, как объявив в классе переменную я могу изменить ее значение внутри функции?

Answer (score 0):

Естественно он будет пустым, так как функцию вы не выполняли. Но если вы сделаете так:

```
listofimagesinfolder = []

def readrasterfolder():
    #КУСОК КОДА ВЫКИНУТ
        listofimagesinfolder.append(filename)

readrasterfolder()

print listofimagesinfolder
```

то пустым он не будет. С областью видимости все в порядке.

Comment: Нет, далее по коду я эту функцию вызываю...

Comment: Я не вижу в вашем коде где вы ее вызываете.
Возможно вы пытаетесь получить данные из listofimagesinfolder до того как вызываете readrasterfolder